# Reading multiple lines from keyboard as input

Tags: c++

For my code, i had to read multiple lines from keyboard. The code i have here does the job. here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

string input;
string line;

cout<< "Enter the input line" << endl;

while (getline(cin, line))
{
    if (line == "^D")
        break;

    input += line;
}

 cout<< "The input entered was: "<<endl;
 cout<< input<< endl;

}
```

The output i get after running this.

```
Enter the input line
Hello
World !
The input entered was: 
HelloWorld !
```

The problem: As you see, the getline does give a white space when printing Hello World. How to make sure it gets printed as "Hello World !" rather than "HelloWorld !"
This happens when there is n newline. It is concatenated with the previous line string and printed.

Comment: You do realized that comparing with the string `"^D"` doesn't compare with CTRL-D, right? CTRL-D (in a Linux/Unix type OS) will end the input with an end of file, so you can't (normally) see it. And even then, the comparison should be for a character of the value 4.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
while (getline(cin, line)) {
    if (line == "^D")
        break;

    input += " " + line;
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking for space as a delimiter (not a "\n").

Answer (score 3):

Just use cin.ignore(); before taking the string input example:

```
cin.ignore();
string s;
getline(cin,s);
```

Comment: but this doesn't work in loops I have a while loop taking multiple input I am using cin.ignore();but it is not accepting some values

Comment: I gave input 12:01 AM and it interprets as 2:01 AM why? It is happening when i take the input 2nd time after the first one